# How to switch to activity when video play stop

Tags: android, android-activity, android-videoview

I am very new to android programming. I am playing a video in VideoView, i want to switch to other activity when video play ends.code is below:

```
VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.samplevideo/"+R.raw.appvideo);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
video.start();
```

What to do to Switch on other Activity when video playing finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register a [`setOnCompletionListener(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29).

```
video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
        // invoke your activity here
    } 
});
```

**Update:** added the missing return type.

Comment: Thanks peter. I have tried your code it gives errors that @override is not allowed here,the type new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method and 'Return type for the method' is missing.

Comment: Thanks finally successful, actually i was making mistakes one was that i did not import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener and other was that i didn't add 'implements OnCompletionListener' to main activity such as public class Main extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener. Cheers!!

Comment: Your Activity does not have to implement OnCompletionListener. I made a mistake - updated.